# getting the name of the function which caused trigger to activate in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, trigger, log

Is there a way to get name of the function/procedure, which contains query, which caused a `TRIGGER` to activate?

For example I have function `update_user_whatever` and it updates user data and I want to log updates to user table with the knowledge of which function caused it (and preferably with its arguments).

-- untested illustrative example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_user_whatever(param int) RETURNS user AS $$
UPDATE user_table SET attr=$1 RETURNING *
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Now can the trigger which is executed on `UPDATE` when running this function access the name on the function? (in this case `update_user_whatever`)

Or is this a wrong way of looking at the problem and a different approach should be chosen?

Comment: What is the actual, underlying problem you are trying to solve with that information?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was hoping I could cheat logging and create a hybrid of app and system auditing, but it probably is a bad idea, so I will abandon this idea a have app logs and server/database logs separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly get the name of the function that contains the statement that caused the data modification that fired the trigger, but you can get the currently executed statement as received from the client:

```
SELECT current_query();
```

(See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE).) In your case, this should be the statement that contains the function call, so you can log at least that statement.

Comment: thank you, this is probably closest one can get.